# How to store correctly MongoDB isodate from php script

Tags: php, mongodb, date

I would like to store dates in a MongoDB collection using PHP et MongoDB Driver.

Here's parts of my scripts :

1st Connexion :

```
    public function process(){
    try{
        $this->connexion = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager($this->dsn);
    }
    catch(\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException $e){
        die("Unable to connect to the MongoDB database : " . $e->getMessage());
    } catch(\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException $e){
        die("General failure : " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

2nd : Document creation

```
    public function process(){
    $dbConnector = dbConnector::instance(); // Instance de connexion à la base de données


    $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

    $query->insert($this->queryArray);

    $writeConcern = new \MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(\MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);
    //$collection = new \MongoCollection($dbConnector->connexion()->db(), $this->store->collectionName());
    try{
        $this->result = $dbConnector->connexion()->executeBulkWrite($dbConnector->dbName() . "." . $this->store->collectionName(), $query, $writeConcern);
    } catch (\MongoDB\Driver\AuthenticationException $e){
        echo "Authentication error : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
    } catch(\MongoDB\Driver\ConnextionException $e){
        echo "Connexion error : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
    }
    catch(\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException $e){
        echo "Runtime error : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

The $queryArray property contains key/value pairs that i want to create.

Have added a conversion method that can manage dates and converts it into MongoDB ISODate :
    use \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime as MongoUTCDate;
    ...
    ...
    public static function toISODate($date){
        if(is_object($date)){
            $dateToString = $date->year . "-" . $date->month . "-" . $date->day;
        } else {
            $dateToString = substr($date,0,10);
        }
        $initDate = new \DateTime($dateToString);

```
    #begin_debug
    #echo "Date from string " . $dateToString . " : " . $initDate->format("d-m-Y") . " (timestamp) " . $initDate->getTimestamp() . "<br />\n";
    #end_debug

    return new MongoUTCDate($initDate->getTimestamp());
}
```

My controller works this way :

```
            $stats->_id = $this->requestData()->_id;

        $stats->purchases = [array(
            "date" => \wp\Database\MongoDB\Utilities\MongoDate::toIsoDate($this->requestData()->date),
            "coords" => array("lat" => $this->requestData()->coords->lat, "lon" => $this->requestData()->coords->lon),
            "metar" => null,
            "quantity" => $this->requestData()->quantity,
            "price" => (float) $this->requestData()->price,
            "peremption" => \wp\Database\MongoDB\Utilities\MongoDate::toIsoDate($this->requestData()->peremption)
        )];

        $stats->insert();
```

When called, document is correctly created but dates are wrong :

```
{
"_id" : "3256222010007",
"purchases" : [ 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("1970-01-18T07:43:01.706Z"),
        "coords" : {
            "lat" : 43.7294742,
            "lon" : 1.416332
        },
        "metar" : null,
        "quantity" : 1,
        "price" : 2.87,
        "peremption" : ISODate("1970-01-18T22:20:34.800Z")
    }
]
}
```

In the previous example, dates would be i.e. the date of the day...

When i log datas, i saw that dates are correctly formed in PHP :

```
Date from string 2017-06-04 : 04-06-2017 (timestamp) 1496527200<br />
```

If convert back timestamp, got the correct date... so, don't understand why Mongo dates are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

For those experiments the same issue, just multiply by 1000 the timestamp given by PHP :

```
    public static function toISODate($date){
    if(is_object($date)){
        $dateToString = $date->year . "-" . $date->month . "-" . $date->day;
    } else {
        $dateToString = substr($date,0,10);
    }
    $initDate = new \DateTime($dateToString);

    #begin_debug
    #echo "Date récupérée à partir de " . $dateToString . " : " . $initDate->format("d-m-Y") . " (timestamp) " . $initDate->getTimestamp() . "<br />\n";
    #end_debug
    $stampedDate = $initDate->getTimestamp() * 1000;

    $mongoUTCDate = new MongoUTCDate($stampedDate);

    return $mongoUTCDate;
}
```

The correct date is stored...

Comment: Thanks for tips `multiply by 1000 with timestamp`